# GraniteDS 3.0.3, Spring 4.0, myBatis 3.2.4, Tomcat 7 Clustering

Tags: spring, tomcat7, hazelcast, graniteds

We have implemented Tomcat 7, Spring 4, myBatis 3.24 and BlazeDS application in cluster. However as number of users are growing we are facing some issues. It was suggested by some friends to replace BlazeDS with GraniteDS and use hazel Cast for clustering and we are evaluating it.

The application currently does not use any messaging; it uses only RemoteObject(Flex) calls to Java services. But a need may arise in future to use messaging and chatting; this is also one of the reason to consider GraniteDS as well. BlazeDS is not being updated that frequently is another reason.

As of today we have succeeded in having a test application working with the required stack. Now we want to test clustering. For BlazeDS jGroup config is required. We searched GDS Docs and web extensively but we could not find any example for GraniteDS clustering. However we found a mention that it supports clustering out of the box. Does it mean that just configuring Tomcat for clustering will achieve what we want, without doing any config to GDS?

Comment: What type of issues are you experiencing with your current BlazeDS setup? Slow application performance?

Comment: When we add third Tomcat Instance to cluster there are strange problems like sometimes its not used at all, few requests take longer to process etc.etc. However since at present its not being actively developed and adobe has handed over flex to apache we feel that we should think of alternative. Your comments on this are welome.